# Junit to test access denied response in spring-rest services depending on the execution environments like local/dev(200/403)

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-profiles

I have a method in rest service which will allow request from environments dev, local and qa. Profiles are configured on that method. I need to write a junit test method, differentiating the environments. Running test methods for allowed environments(dev, local and qa) it should return http status 200 otherwise 403.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us what you have done so far, add some code and the results. Make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ActiveProfiles` annotation on your test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "dev")
Public class MyTest {
    // test
}
```

Refer to [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/).